# Missing x86 system image in android sdk manager

Tags: android, adt

I was downloading the x86 system image from android sdk manager but due to network outage the download was interrupted. Once, the network connection is back, I can't see any system images in sdk manager now. This is how it looks like:
[image]

I tried reloading the Packages but it does not help. How should I bring them back in android sdk manager? Please help. I am stuck.

Comment: what do you have in folder <sdk>/temp ?

Comment: google_apis_x86-19_r02.zip and google_apis_x86-19_r02.zip.inf. This was the image I was downloading when connection was interrupted.

Comment: remove/move it and try again

Comment: Tried removing but still no difference.